# Continuously updating a UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am creating an application that will constantly update the coordinates of a plane node upon detection of an image. However, I want to know how I would do this. My code is the following:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
                var imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name  else { return }

            let planeNode = self.getPlaneNode(withReferenceImage: imageAnchor.referenceImage)
            planeNode.opacity = 1.0
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            planeNode.runAction(self.fadeAction)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

            let nodeCam = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera
            let cameraTransform = nodeCam.transform
            planeNode.position.x = cameraTransform.columns.3.x + 1
            planeNode.position.y = cameraTransform.columns.3.y + 1


            if imageName == "sample" {
                self.imageOne.text = "\"\(imageName)\""
                self.instructions.text = "IMAGE DETECTED: \"\(imageName)\""
                self.coordinateView.isHidden = false
                self.updateOne.isHidden = false
                self.coordinateX.text = "X: " + String(planeNode.position.x)
                self.coordinateY.text = "Y: " + String(planeNode.position.y)
            }
```

How would I make it so that the labels corresponding to coordinate X and coordinate Y would continuously change and update when the plane node moves? I have tried repeat loops where:

```
repeat {
   self.coordinateX.text = "X: " + String(planeNode.position.x)
   self.coordinateY.text = "Y: " + String(planeNode.position.y)
} while imageName == "sample"
```

but this only causes the code to freeze upon detection of the image. Any suggestions?

Comment: When are calling the `renderer` function and `repeat` snippet?

Comment: Is the `renderer` method what's moving the plane node on screen?

Comment: Yes, that's the main method moving the plane node.

Comment: Are you using ARWorldTracking or ARimageTracking configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Two options here; you could set up a DispatchSource that registers a scheduled event and established a handler.  That handler could be the function that sets the point into the label. Example:

```
func startUpdating() {
    timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    timer?.schedule(deadline: DispatchTime.now(),
                    repeating: DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(16),
                             leeway: .milliseconds(5))
    timer?.setEventHandler(qos: .userInitiated, flags: [], handler: self.update)
    timer?.resume()
}

func update() {
    coordinateX.title = String(planeNode.position.x)
    coordinateY.title = String(planeNode.position.y)
}
```

This works great if you think that the data will update/change a lot within short periods of time.

If you don't think that will happen, then I would just use "didSet" to monitor the variables and set that function within the "didSet" function.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that I have an `ARReferenceImage` which is called `BlackMirrorz`.

In the following `ARSCNViewDelegate`. method I am loading my model when the `ARReferenceImage` is detected like so:

```
//-------------------------
//MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
//-------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check We Have A Valid Image Anchor
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        //2. Get The Detected Reference Image
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

        //3. Load Our Model Only If Our Reference Image Name Is Valid & The Model Hasnt Already Been Placed
        if let matchedTargetImageName = referenceImage.name, matchedTargetImageName == "BlackMirrorz" && !modelPlaced {

            //a. Set Our Model To The Size Of The ReferenceImage
            let model = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height))

            //b. Rotate It
            model.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

            //c. Add It To Our Node
            node.addChildNode(model)

            //d. Name Our Node
            node.name = matchedTargetImageName

        }
    }
}
```

Of importance here is the final line of code; in which I have provided the `ARImageAnchor's` Node a name, which will make it easy for us to track later.

Having loaded our model, we can then make use of the following `ARSessionDelegate` Method:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) { }
```

Which simply:

> Tells the delegate that the session has adjusted the properties of one
>   or more anchors.

As such it easy to update any `Labels`, `SCNText's` or alike with the current coordinates of your `ARImageAnchor` e.g:

```
//--------------------------
//MARK: -  ARSessionDelegate
//--------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate{

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        //1. Enumerate Through Our Current ARAnchors
        for anchor in anchors{

            //2. If We Have An ARImageAnchor Then Get The Corresponding Node & Check That It's Name Is The One We Want To Track
            if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
                let targetNode = self.augmentedRealityView.node(for: imageAnchor), targetNode.name == "BlackMirrorz"{

                //3. Get The Transform For The Anchor And Log This To The Console Or Update Your Labels
                print("""
                    Current Position X Of Anchor = \(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.x)
                    Current Position Y Of Anchor = \(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y)
                    Current Position Z Of Anchor = \(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)
                    """)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it points you in the right direction...